# Image properties dialog in CKEditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I recently upgraded from CKeditor 4 to CKeditor 5.

The old one used to have a very nice image properties dialog where you could configure borders etc.:

[image: ckeditor4 screenshot]

Unfortunately, CKeditor 5 only has a text field to paste the image URL, and nothing else. There's also a simple toolbar to change floating etc. of images, and the [ckeditor image-styles documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-styles.html) seems to suggest that they prefer people to use semantic styling instead of just setting borders, sizes, etc. directly.

However, this if a huge mess when you have an existing webapp where people were used to the flexibility the old editor gave them.

Is there a config option I missed (or a plugin that can be enabled) in CKeditor 5 to get these advanced image controls back?

Answer (score -1):

There is a CKFinder plugin for CKEditor5, this should help you get back the functionality that has been lost, here's a link https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/image-upload.html#ckfinder

Here's the features of this plugin

> CKFinder
>
> The CKFinder feature provides a bridge between the rich-text editor
> and CKFinder, a browser-based commercial file uploader with its
> server-side connectors (PHP, Java and ASP.NET).
>
> There are two ways you can integrate CKEditor 5 with the CKFinder file
> manager:
>
> With the server-side connector only – In this scenario, images dropped
> or pasted into the editor are uploaded to the CKFinder server-side
> connector running on your server.
>
> With both the server-side connector and the client-side file manager
> (recommended) – Images dropped and pasted into the editor are uploaded
> to the server (like in the first option).
>
> But there are more cool features available, for instance:
>
> - **uploading** using the full user interface,
> - **browsing** previously uploaded images,
> - **editing** images (cropping, resizing, etc.),
> - **organizing** or deleting images.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Not really, this is 1) commercial software, and 2) a full-blown file manager. Also, I do not want to edit the file but simply style it at display time (with CSS).

Comment: @ThiefMaster have you found a solution to this ? also agree CKFinder is not the right answer.